# Is not abstract and does not override abstract method onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)

Tags: android, firebase

I want to add Google Sign-in module to in my project.I checked similar topics about this error.And I tried solution given,but it's not work on my case.
 I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImM2sTvs1H0)

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener(){
            @Override
            public void OnConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult  connectionResult) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
```

**Error Log:**

error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult) in OnConnectionFailedListener

error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s just a typo. You need to override `onConnectionFailed` not `OnConnectionFailed` (without an uppercase).

Here are the docs: [GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)

Comment: Thank you @kAliert